# How to create a simple HashMap with Integers?

Tags: java, dictionary

Following situation:
We have a Vector with elements and want to map each element to an integer. The mapping of the elements should be exactly like the index of the element inside the vector. Example:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
v.add("s1");
v.add("s2");
```

Mapping should be:

```
"s1" -> 0
"s2" -> 1
```

Approach 1: Use `v.indexOf("s1")` to get the integer. But this approach is slow, since the correct index has to be searched for each time.

Approach 2: Create a `HashMap` and use `put` in a for loop to put each element to the map.

Approach 2 is okay, but is there a nicer solution to create the Map more directly ?

Comment: Why would you want to have such a mapping? And please use `ArrayList` rather than legacy `Vector`.

Comment: @RohitJain - That's not really relevant to the question.  And besides, he may have a legitimate reason to use `Vector`.

Comment: why in first place do you have a vector than, if you need an ordered Map (i assume you need to keep track of your add operation) you may use `OrderedMap`

Comment: There isn't any nicer solution. But I don't see what's not nice about it. It's just 2 lines of code. Beware that if your Vector contains duplicates, you'll lose information.

Comment: off topic. I know that Vector i thread safe and slower than ArrayList(not thread safe). can you give reasons of using vector please?

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak - Because you might *need* a `List` that is thread-safe.  Or because you are using some other (old) API that *requires* you to use a `Vector`.  Cases where `Vector` is the right choice are pretty unusual ... but they *do* exist.

Answer (score 1):

If `Map`s where conceived for such purposes, why does it seem odd to you? I know, it's a simple mapping and using a `Map` can seem really pompous for a simple task such as getting the index of a given string.

But think about this, approach 1 behaves like a `Map<Integer,String>` where you seek by value and get its related key so you can stick to the reverse `Map<String,Integer>` unless you're restricted to using a `Vector`.

I just fear this is one of those cases where someone takes the "performance vs memory" discussion to the nano-level.

Comment: Thank you. It's not about performance for me. I wondered if there is some built-in function to do the task more directly. But since this is not the case, approach 2 is fine for me.

Comment: You're welcome. You know, a `Map` could seem like a workaround for something like this but, normally, the index of a certain object in a collection is determined through search.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a HashMap that you may want to consider is just using an ArrayList of your strings with a Collections.binarySearch to get the integer value. Depending on how many elements you plan on having this may perform on par with a HashMap approach.

Comment: binarySearch requires the list to be sorted, which is quite a strong requirement.

Comment: @JB Nizet - The question's 'solution 2' seems to hint that all of the needed elements are already present and can be added in proper order.

Comment: Ah, so you mean that he could create a sorted copy of the vector and use binary search on this sorted copy. If so, then yes, he can do that. But I don't really see what the gain over a map would be.

Comment: @JB Nizet - There would be gains in memory footprint and for small sets there would be a computational time improvement as well.

Comment: Unfortunatley my Vector is not sorted, but this is a nice idea.

Comment: @John Threepwood - depending on your use case, doing the Collection.sort may not be an issue. If you're building the list at start up and expect ~million look-ups then the computational time spent sorting would be insignificant.

Answer (score -1):

> but is there a nicer solution to the the Map directly ?

`HashMap` will be the most appropriate data structure to use.

> How to create a simple HashMap with Integers?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> aHMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
aHMap.put("S1", 0); 
aHMap.get("S1");
```

OR

```
HashMap<Integer, String> aHMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
aHMap.put(0, "S1"); 
aHMap.get(0);
```

Comment: Have you read question carefully? *Approach 2: Create a HashMap and use put in a for loop to put each element to the map.*

Comment: @Azodious the question was not about how to implement the approach, but are there better ways. It was also not about if hashmap is a good data structure or not, but are there more direct ways of instantiating it.

Comment: @Azodious I'm agree with eis